# Completion pop-ups hijack arrow keys. Any way to disable that?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me

Regardless of which code completion plugin I use (I tried asyncomplete and YouCompleteMe), when there's a completion pop-up, up and down arrow keys select completion options in it instead of moving the cursor. How do I disable this behavior? For me, tab is enough to cycle through completions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remap `<up>` key to close `popup menu` and move cursor up when `popup menu` is visible:

```
inoremap <expr> <up> pumvisible() ? '<c-e><up>' : '<up>'
```

[:h :map-expression](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression)
[:h complete_CTRL-E](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#complete_CTRL-E)
[:h pumvisible()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#pumvisible%28%29)

Comment: Thanks. I replaced `<c-e>` with `<c-y>` to insert the selected completion (my question was probably poorly phrased), works like a charm. `<c-e>` reverts the line to "what you typed" state regardless of whether there was a selected completion.